# How to deploy applications(war file) to IBM WebSphere using Ansible?

Tags: automation, ansible, websphere

I was trying to automate the deployment process of WAR files to IBM WebSphere using Ansible.
I could find examples of playbooks for starting and stopping the services, but I was looking for the playbook code to deploy the WAR files to the server using Ansible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Ansible expert so this is only draft of the steps.
You can install application using `wsadmin.sh` tool see [Commands for the AdminApp object using wsadmin scripting](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=sclrmuws-commands-adminapp-object-using-wsadmin-scripting#rxml_adminapp__cmd7) .
The installation procedure  could look like this:

- `scp` your war file to the target machine (dmgr in clustered environment)
- execute `wsadmin` on target machine, something like:

```
$ DMGR_HOME\bin\wsadmin.sh -c "AdminApp.install(path_to_app_on_remote_server/myapp.war', [-appname myappname])"
```

Here is an ansible wsadmin module, but dont know it it will be more useful to you https://github.com/amimof/ansible-websphere/blob/master/library/wsadmin.py